# Wordpress + React и стоит ли?

Tags: wordpress, reactjs

Уважаемые старейшины и знатоки Wordpress. В изысканиях силы и мощи пришёл к изучению REACT и дальнейшей цепочке мыслей как его совместить с Wordpress. Много статей и видео поведал на англоязычных просторах интернета. Понял что да - прикольно, быстро, современно. НО одно большое НО которое упускалось во всех туториалах о котором с самого начала мне кричала чуйка. На сколько я понял, что если мы делаем приложение полностью отдельно чисто на Rest API то мы автоматически говорим до свидания всевозможным плагинам которые мы можем подключить как и SEO ибо как получить wp_head / wp_footer с REST человеческим образом без костылей я не нашёл а именно в них заключено как Seo так и подключение всех сторонних пресовских вещей. Аля мы просто получаем быстрый сайт с роутингом без перезагрузок но теряем возможность подключать всякие там Yoast SEO и тп. С другой стороны можно запарится и оставить php часть и подключить сторонне реакт но тогда такая конструкция будет максимально запутанной и на верх делать приславутый роутинг не выйдет ибо wp_head как то та должен обновляться, а совать его в отдельный API  и получать при обновлении - костыль. Короче говоря, прошу мудрецов помочь советом, поправить где я наговорил ереси, и ответить стоит ли вообще запариватся с тепой на Реакте, наставьте невежду на путь истинный, так сказать.

Answer (score 3):

WordPress использует React уже несколько лет. Библиотека полностью интегрирована в ядро WordPress. Визуальный редактор Gutenberg (он же - редактор блоков - построен на React). Многие плагины уже используют React. Нет никаких проблем получить любые сведения из базы WordPress через REST.

Answer (score 3):

Предлагаю также обратить внимание на генераторы статики, например Gatsby или Frontity. Они написаны на React, Frontity разработан специально для WordPress командой Automattic, Gatsby активно интегрируется с WordPress, команда разрабатывает для этого специальные решения.
Генераторы статики позволят вам наслаждаться мощью React, используя WordPress в качестве headless бэкенда. Они включают в себя server side rendering, так что ваши SEO-специалисты тоже будут довольны.
Так как генераторы статики становятся все более и более популярными, крупные игроки рынка плагинов обязательно подтянутся (некоторые уже) и предложат свои интеграции.